# JavaScript - Reverse Array with empty field and add it to the old array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I have an array which has empty fields.
Particulary it looks as following:

```
array() {[4]  => 3,[8]  => 6,[17] => 24}
```

I am using it this way because I am drawing a graph with it. So for an example: at 4cm the graph has a height of 3cm. And so on. 

Now the problem is that the formula only calculates half of the values, since the second part of the graph is just mirrored. So I need to remove the last part of the array and then reverse the rest, while maintaining their distance from that removed value in the original array.

I need a algorhythm which can calculate this for me.

```
array() {[26] =>6, [30] => 3}
```

Comment: I do not understand the process by which you are transforming the first array into the second. Where do 26 and 30 come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think an array not a great datatype for this, since you might have potentially thousands of `undefined` values in it, but filling the array with the missing values is rather easy. You just traverse the array backwards and push the values encountered to the array.

```
var ar = [/*your input*/];

/* ar.length-1 would be the last position of your array
   so you want to go from position ar.lenght-2 */
for (var i = ar.length-2;i>=0;i--){ar.push(ar[i])}
```

It might be better to use an object instead, so you can work with key value pairs representing your graph nodes.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it works perfectly, but follow the logic. Lets say that your original array is `a`
.

```
a.fill(0).concat(a.reverse().slice(1));
```

First reverse the original array, and remove the first element (which is the last element of the original array). Then concat the filling zero original array(delete all value, you can fill undefined or other value) with the reversed one. Boom, you get your new array.